# Where to ask a question regarding shared mailbox in Exchange Server 2016- Office 365

Tags: support, site-recommendation

We are dangerously close to maxing out a mailbox size and would like to get some suggestions on what to do. Where should we ask about this? When searching for questions on Exchange Server, found that Server Fault and Super User both have categories. Server Fault has the most activity but the Office 365 Exchange has no activity.

Comment: Self hosted exchange, and office 365's hosted flavour are fairly different beasts. I suspect this is distinct from the dupe.